# Run sql query on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandasql

I have a dataframe df

| ID | Price | Region |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | AUS |
| 1 | 45 | DXB |
| 2 | 25 | GER |
| 2 | 18 | TUN |

I want to write a code in python to get the following output

| ID | Price | Region |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 45 | DXB |
| 2 | 25 | TUN |

I have tried using pandasql to get the output but it is not giving the output I want

The code I have tried is

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as ps

#to read table
df=pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")

ps.sqldf("select ID, max(Price), Region from df order by ID")
```

If there is any other code in python itself (without using pandasql) that can get the above output, please let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby.transform`

```
output_df = df[df['Price'].eq(df.groupby("ID")['Price'].transform("max"))]
```

Or with `ps.sqldf` using window function to get the max price and then return rows where Price equals max price:

```
output_df  = ps.sqldf("""select ID,Price,Region from 
                        (select *, max(Price) over (partition by ID) max_Price from df)
                        where Price = max_Price""")
```

---

```
    ID  Price Region
0   1     45    DXB
1   2     25    GER
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df.sort_values('Price').drop_duplicates('ID', keep='last')
```